# Text not following CSS formatting when content is added below

Tags: html, css

Please bare in mind that I am new to code!

So I have a header and some text, that I am wanting to place on top of a background image that i have input using CSS, therefore the positioning is key.

It was all working fine, until i added more HTML content under neither the text. From this it was just as if the text wasn't picking up my CSS instructions.

HTML:

```
 <div id="sidemicro">
 <text class="circleheader"><h3>Special Occasion?</h3><p>Give us a call and </br> we'll see how     we can make </br> your tour  extra special!</p></br>
```

This is the text i need to format:

```
 <div id="form">
 <form action ='otterabout.php' method='POST'>
*Your Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br />
*Your Email: <input type'text' name='email'><br />
*Date of visit: <input type'date' name='date'><br />
*Time of visit: <input type'time' name='time'><br />
*Group Size: <input type'text' name='groupsize'><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
<input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the content under the text which has stopped it formatting.

CSS:

```
.circleheader {
margin-top:70%;
margin-left:15%;

}



.circletext {
text-align:center;
margin-left:35%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle. Check out http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: FYI, `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` in percentage is respective to width but not height.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the type of formatting you're looking for? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLSSd/).

CSS

```
.sidemicro {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/roadtrippers/image/upload/v1396514626/p2nmpjpgjsm8iihdh5ip.jpg');
    background-size: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.circleheader {
  width: 200px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}
```